# Finding the digit in the units place

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Find the digit in the units place of the number $2009!+3^{7886}$.

The options available are:

- a) $7$
- b) $3$
- c) $1$
- d) $9$

Comment: What is the units digit of $2009!$?  (Is it a multiple of ten?)  What is the units digit of $3^4$?  $(3^4)^2$?  $3^{4k}$ for any positive integer $k$?  $3^{7886}$?

Comment: 7886 is not divisible by 4, so it's impossible to say the units digit of 3^7886 is 1?

Comment: $7886 = 7884 + 2$, so $3^{7886} = 3^{7884+2} = 3^{7884}\cdot 3^2$ has units digit...

Comment: Notice $3^{4n + k} = (3^4)^n*3^k = 81^n*3^k$.  $81^n$ will have 1 in the units place so $3^{4n+k}$ will have the same digit value as $3^k$. There are only four possibilities k = 0, and digit is 1.  k= 1 and digit is 3.  k = 2 and digit is 9.  Or k = 3 and digit is 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS:

- $\forall{n}\geq5:n!\equiv0\pmod{10}$
- $\forall{n}:3^n\equiv3^{n\bmod4}\pmod{10}$

Comment: Oh, so it's 9? Thank you :)

Comment: @b_boundary: Made it slightly more general